# How to get start/end date from single date column from a SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you please help me to get a solution for my issue. I am using a SQL Server database, and I want to get end date from the start date + month or day.

- if month was not null add it to the start date to get the end date
- if day was not null add it to the start date to get the end date

I have this table:

```
| ID | startdate |  month |  day  | 
| 1  | 2019-03-05|   3    | null  |
| 2  | 2019-03-05|  null  |   30  |
```

Desired output:

```
| ID | startdate |  month |  day  |  enddate  |
| 1  | 2019-03-05|   3    | null  |2019-06-05 |
| 2  | 2019-03-05|  null  |   30  |2019-04-04 |
```

Could you please help me to write a SQL query please?

Comment: When you will add 30 days in 5 March 2019 it will give 4 April 2019 not the 5 April so correct it in your desired output. It is because march month is for the 31 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query using Dateadd() function. The [**DATEADD()**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp) function adds a time/date interval to a date and then returns the date.

```
create table tblMonth (Id int, startdate date, month int, day int)
insert into tblMonth values
( 1, '2019-03-05', 3, null),
(1, '2019-03-05', null, 30)

Select Id, startdate, month, day, DATEADD(MM, isnull(month,0), startDate) AS endDate
    from tblMonth
```

To add date with checking you can use case statement as shown below.

```
Select Id, startdate, month, day, 
    case when month is null then 
            DATEADD(dd, isnull(day, 0), startDate) 
        else
            DATEADD(mm, isnull(month,0), startDate) 
        end
    AS endDate
from tblMonth
```

[**Live Demo**](https://rextester.com/WJJS34967)

Comment: it work with the month but the day in the example didn't work

Comment: @ahmed check the modified query.

Comment: @ahmed Request you to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: what if month and day both columns will have value?

Comment: @Mukesh Arora it is not a big deal & OP know better than us how to handle and what to do in that case but in my case else part will work .

Answer (score 1):

**You can use below query to get the desired result**

```
declare @TestDate table
(id int, startdate date, [month] int, [day] int)

insert into @TestDate
values
(1, '2019-03-05', 3, null)

insert into @TestDate
values
(1, '2019-03-05',  null, 30)

select Id,
    startdate,
    [month],
    [day],
    dateadd(day, isnull(day, 0), dateadd(month, isnull([month], 0), startdate)) as enddate
from @TestDate
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below - using `dateadd()` function

```
select id, 
       startdate, 
       dateadd(case when month is null then dd else mm, coalesce(month,day),startdate) as enddate
from tablename
```